# Prevent a control in accordion header from triggering accordion roll-up/down behaviour

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Given an Ajax Control Toolkit accordion:

```
<ajaxToolkit:Accordion runat="server"
    SelectedIndex="0"
    HeaderCssClass="accordionHeader"
    HeaderSelectedCssClass="accordionHeaderSelected"
    ContentCssClass="accordionContent"
    AutoSize="None"
    FadeTransitions="true"
    TransitionDuration="250"
    FramesPerSecond="40"
    RequireOpenedPane="false"
    SuppressHeaderPostbacks="true">
```

with a button paired with a ConfirmButtonExtender in the HeaderTemplate:

```
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:Button 
            ID="PushPlanButton" 
            Text="Push" 
            runat="server" 
            OnClick="PushPlanButtonPressed" />

        <ajaxToolkit:ConfirmButtonExtender 
            ID="ConfirmButtonExtender1" 
            runat="server" 
            TargetControlID="PushPlanButton" 
            ConfirmText="Please confirm" />
    </HeaderTemplate>
```

When the button is clicked, the modal messagebox comes up, "Please confirm", as expected.

When the user dismisses it, the Accordion thinks it's been clicked and closes up the active panel, which is not desired.

Any way to suppress this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

The best choice in my opinion is to tweak AjaxControlToolkit sources in accordance with your needs. In this case you just needt to make bit change in `confirmButtonBehavior.pre.js` file. Rewrite `_onClick` method as below:

```
_onClick: function (e) {
    /// <summary>
    /// Button's click handler to display the confirmation dialog
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e" type="Sys.UI.DomEvent">
    /// Event info
    /// </param>

    if (this.get_element() && !this.get_element().disabled) {
        if (this._ConfirmOnFormSubmit) {
            // Note that this behavior was triggered (for later)
            Sys.Extended.UI.ConfirmButtonBehavior._clickedBehavior = this;
        } else {
            // Display the dialog and cancel the click if necessary
            if (!this._displayConfirmDialog()) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation(); // added to prevent event bubbling
                return false;
            }
            else if (this._oldScript) {

                if (String.isInstanceOfType(this._oldScript)) {
                    eval(this._oldScript);
                }
                else if (typeof (this._oldScript) == 'function') {
                    this._oldScript();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But if you can't tweak library sources by some reasons, you can apply another approach. Add script below onto the page:

```
function pageLoad()
{
     var extender = $find("<%= ConfirmButtonExtender1.ClientID %>");
     $removeHandler(extender.get_element(), "click", extender._clickHandler);

     extender._clickHandler = Function.createDelegate(extender, function (e) {
          if (this.get_element() && !this.get_element().disabled) {
               if (this._ConfirmOnFormSubmit) {
                    // Note that this behavior was triggered (for later)
                    Sys.Extended.UI.ConfirmButtonBehavior._clickedBehavior = this;
               } else {
                    // Display the dialog and cancel the click if necessary
                    if (!this._displayConfirmDialog()) {
                         e.preventDefault();
                         e.stopPropagation();
                         return false;
                    }
                    else if (this._oldScript) {

                         if (String.isInstanceOfType(this._oldScript)) {
                              eval(this._oldScript);
                         }
                         else if (typeof (this._oldScript) == 'function') {
                              this._oldScript();
                         }
                    }
               }
          }
     });
     $addHandler(extender.get_element(), "click", extender._clickHandler);
}
```

Comment: You sir, are a genius. I've not tried this out yet but it's obviously been researched. I will try it out shortly and post back. Thanks so much!